# Backbone.js Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have written the flowing backbone.js program :

```
<script>

        var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
        var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
           template: _.template($('#posttemplate').html()),
           intialize: function() {
              console.log("intializing view");
           },
           render: function() {
              console.log("rendering..");
              var htmloutput = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
              $('#postcontainer').html(htmloutput);
              return this;
           }
        });         

       $(document).ready(function() {
           var postmodel = new PostModel({title: "hello"});
           var postview = new PostView({model: postmodel});
           postview.render();
        });


    </script type="text/javascript">



<script type="text/template" id="posttemplate">
        <div> Title: <%= title %> , post: <%= post %> </div>
</script>

<div class="container" id="postcontainer"></div>
```

when i run the code i get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

but it works perfectly fine when i put 
template = _.template($('#posttemplate').html()); into the render function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to access the template before it exists. The HTML document is parsed from the top to the bottom and when you have

`template: _.template($('#posttemplate').html())`

then the `$('#posttemplate')` selector does not return any results because the element containing the template hasn't been parsed yet.

Try moving the

```
<script type="text/template" id="posttemplate">
        <div> Title: <%= title %> , post: <%= post %> </div>
</script>
```

element up above your first script element.

The reason it works when you put it in the `render` function is that `render` is called after the document fires a ready event, at which point the template exists.